# send text with jquery and timer

Tags: jquery, timer

The idea for my script is to send text from a select menu or a text field to a text area. So far I am able to get the select menu working when I pick an option, but for the text field when i type something it doesn't send anything. Also I would like to add a time to this script so that when a user selects an option or types something in it will send.

Right now it only works woth the select menu...not sure how to also make it work for the text field and add the timer :(

```
<select id="status" name="status">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Away">Away</option>
    <option value="Busy">Busy</option>
    <option value="Out To Lunch">Out To Lunch</option>
    <option value="Offline">Offline</option>
</select>

<input name="custom_status" type="text">

<div id="counter"></div>
```

as

```
$(function() { 
$("#status").change(function() {
   $("textarea[name=mess]", parent.frames['form'].document).val($(this).val());
 });

$("#custom_status").change(function() {
   $("textarea[name=mess]", parent.frames['form'].document).val($(this).val());
 });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to add id to custom status:

```
<input id="custom_status" name="custom_status" type="text" />
```

Then you can run function on both parts at the same time:

```
$("#status, #custom_status").bind('change keyup',function(){
    $("textarea[name=mess]", parent.frames['form'].document).val($(this).val());
});
```

And handle timeout like this:

```
var callAway = false;

$('body').bind('mousemove keyup',function(){
    clearTimeout(callAway);
    callAway = setTimeout(function(){
        $("#counter").text("Away");
    },5000);
})
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eC9L6/

Comment: Moon in your script is the timer suppose to start when you type something?

Comment: The timer starts when the mouse is moved, or a key is released on the whole document. From that point on, it triggers every 5 seconds (should be changed) and resets the timer after any mousemove/keyup on the document.

Comment: ah! i see now...instead of showing "Away" every X number of times how would i show "#status or #custom_status" every x number of times and display it in the textarea[name=mess] not the div.I wanted to use the counter div to display the counter number counting down

Comment: In the fiddle, I put the output in the div as a demonstration. As with most programming, there is an input, some processing and an output. With javascript, the syntax can sometimes be overbearing. jQuery both makes the syntax easier, and often employs smarter methods to achieve the same goal. The basic idea is this - you select something (usually something in the DOM and visible on the page) and then do something to it (maybe move it, or attach some data to it). So if you want to show something in `textarea[name=mess]` just do `$('textarea[name=mess]').html('the thing you want to show')`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name='custom_status']").change(function() {
   $("textarea[name=mess]", parent.frames['form'].document).val($(this).val());
});
```

or

```
$("[name='custom_status']").bind('keyup change', function() {
   $("textarea[name=mess]", parent.frames['form'].document).val($(this).val());
});
```

Your selector is wrong, there's no input with the id custom_status, but an input with the name custom_status.